# Linux syscall clock_settime(...) fails with EPERM in Docker container

Tags: c, linux, docker, ubuntu, time

Tl;dr: When I try executing the clock_settime(...) linux syscall in an Ubuntu 18.04 container it fails with an EPERM error despite the program running as root. Running the exact same program as root outside of the container on Ubuntu 18.04 succeeds.

The program is as follows:

```
/*  main.c: This program sets the clock forward 1 day. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void )
{
    struct timespec stime;

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stime) == -1 ) {
        perror( "getclock" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    stime.tv_sec += (60*60)*24L;  /* Add one day */
    stime.tv_nsec = 0;

    if( clock_settime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stime) == -1 ) {
        perror( "setclock" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

(Taken from https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/qnx/clock_settime.html)

When running outside of the container, the date is successfully updated:

```
# gcc main.c -o pushtime
# date && ./pushtime && date
Wed Dec 12 09:38:36 PST 2018
Tue Dec 11 09:38:38 PST 2018
```

When running inside of the container, an EPERM error is raised:

```
# gcc main.c -o pushtime
# docker run -it -v `pwd`:/workspace ubuntu:bionic /workspace/pushtime
setclock: Operation not permitted
```

Given that the commands are running as root, I'm confused why there would be an error with permissions and I haven't found anything yet in Docker's documentation that explains why.

**Edit:** I just realized that an easier demonstration of the error is as follows:

```
root@host:~# sudo docker run -it ubuntu:bionic /bin/bash
root@container:/# date -s '2018-02-01 21:39'
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Thu Feb  1 21:39:00 UTC 2018
```

Comment: I'd certainly *hope* it would fail -- if a container could set the time for your entire host, that's not exactly effective isolation.

Comment: Yea, in hindsight the answer should have been obvious. For whatever reason I didn't consider that the container shares the system clock with the host. Since the clock lives in the kernel and the host and container share the same kernel it stands to reason that they also share the clock.

Comment: It looks like there've been [proposals](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1809.2/03853.html) to implement a time namespace (just as there are existing filesystem/procfs/network/etc namespaces for kernel facilities Docker can isolate today), so containers could have their own clocks -- maybe someday in the future this Q&A entry will be outdated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Aha, the short answer is that the `--privileged` flag needs to be passed when running the container.

From the Docker documentation:

> Full container capabilities (--privileged)
>
> $ docker run -t -i --rm ubuntu bash
>
> root@bc338942ef20:/# mount -t tmpfs none /mnt
>
> mount: permission denied
>
> This will not work, because by default, most potentially dangerous kernel capabilities are dropped; including cap_sys_admin (which is required to mount filesystems). However, the --privileged flag will allow it to run...